# Create empty copy of raster with python GDAL API

Tags: python, raster, gdal

I want to create empty copies of my raw raster files (TIFFs in this particular case) at another location and then fill them with values later on.

Of course I could just create copies or translate and fill with zeros, and so on ... but I'm assuming just creating the empty files would be most efficient.

Here's a quick function which I put together, it's quite fast but I was wondering if gdal has a dedicated method for that.

```
import gdal
import os

def fun(x,p):
    ds = gdal.Open(x)
    dr = ds.GetDriver()
    ds_new = dr.Create(p+os.path.basename(x),ds.RasterXSize,ds.RasterYSize,ds.RasterCount,ds.GetRasterBand(1).DataType)
    ds_new.SetGeoTransform(ds.GetGeoTransform())
    ds_new.SetProjection(ds.GetProjection())
    ds = None
    ds_new = None

%%timeit
fun('testras.tif','/home/test/')

# 601 µs ± 8.08 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```